# Repositioned standardWindowButton moves back to the top

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-elcapitan, appkit, nstitlebaraccessoryviewcontroller

I am repositioning the `NSWindow` standard buttons like so:

`NSButton *closeButton = [self standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton];
[closeButton setFrameOrigin: NSMakePoint(50,20)];`

This works perfectly until a present a modal sheet on the window, at which point the button jumps up to the top left (where it would normally be). I want to center it in the title bar (which has been increased in height using a `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController`.

This has only started happening since *El Capitan* and I can't get it to reposition back to the center automatically. I've tried observing for window events and force a relayout, but it resets after a while. Any way to reposition these buttons and make them 'stick'?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up observing `NSViewDidUpdateTrackingAreasNotification` on each of the buttons and then repositioning them again. It seems the OS keeps updating the position without reason.